# SQL query to select one registered version for each mainversion

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am busy with creating a query to select one registered version for each main version.

The query to select all registered versions for one customer looks like this:

```
select JobReportFKEmpId, JobRecChangeDate, JobRecCreateDate, _JobBldvId RegisteredVersion, left(_JobBldvId,5) MainVersion, _JobDTAPId from dba.Job
where JobCusId = '36811'
and JobContext = '1099511627776'
and _JobDTAPId = 'P'
group by JobReportFKEmpId, JobRecChangeDate, JobRecCreateDate,_JobBldvId, _JobDTAPId
order by 4 desc
```

Which results in the following output
[image: Output query]

My output needs to be:
3 records containing the highest registered version for each main version. So:

- 19.04.22 for 19.04
- 16.10.45 for 16.10
- 15.10.23 for 15.10

Now i have created the following query:

```
SELECT
   JobReportFKEmpId, JobRecChangeDate, JobRecCreateDate, max(_JobBldvId) , left(_JobBldvId,5) Bldv, _JobDTAPId

FROM
    (SELECT
       *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY left(_JobBldvId,5) ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn
    FROM
       dba.Job WHERE JobCusId = '36811'
and JobContext = '1099511627776'
and _JobDTAPId = 'P'
    ) foo
   WHERE rn = 1
   group by JobReportFKEmpId, JobRecChangeDate, JobRecCreateDate,_JobBldvId, _JobDTAPId
   order by 4 desc
```

Which giving me the following output:

[image: Query output]

So who can improve my query to get the correct output.

Comment: Probably needs to be at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your versions appear to be well-formated, so you can use window functions:

```
select j.*
from (select j.*,
             left(_JobBldvId, 5) as MainVersion,
             row_number() over (partition by JobReportFKEmpId order by left(_JobBldvId, 5) desc) as seqnum
      from dba.Job j
      where JobCusId = '36811' and
            JobContext = '1099511627776' and
            _JobDTAPId = 'P'
     ) j;
```